# Why are there so many neutral wires in light switch and how do they work with a smart dimmer light switch?

Tags: wiring, light, dimmer-switch, neutral

I am having difficulty installing a smart dimmer light switch.
I have 3 switches, 2 switches are on one breaker and one is on the other breaker. The problem I believe has something to do with the neutral wires.
All of the 3 original light switches only use the black and red wire, however, there is a ground wire in the box meant for each switch and 5 neutral wires all spliced together.
I am only changing out one of the older light switches for a smart dimmer and leaving the other two regular switches. I have troubleshot by connecting each of the five neutral wires with the new smart dimmer.
When I connect the neutral wire that appears to be connected to the old regular light switch (that shares a breaker with the new dimmer switch) all the lights work for both switches but flash on and off and the smart dimmer has power.
If I connect the neutral wire that is meant for the older switch on the other breaker then that light switch’s lights do not work but the dimmers lights work perfectly and the dimmer has power.
If I connect the dimmer's neutral wire to the dimmer then there is no power to the dimmer and the lights that should work for it do not work.
If I connect either of the two other neutral wires that don’t appear to have a switch for them but are just extra wires, then the dimmer switch has no power, the dimmers lights don’t work but the other two regular switches lights work.
I’m not sure if there is a correct combination of neutral wires to the dimmer switch but I can’t seem to figure it out. If anyone can give me some pointers that would be much appreciated.

Sorry I did not take a picture of what it originally looked like. I have placed numbers where the wires are in the picture. 4/5 wires have one coming from top and one coming from bottom of box. All 5 were originally spliced together under the red cap.
[image: picture of current box]

Here is close up inside the box currently.
[image: another closer pic of current situation]

Comment: *2 switches are on one breaker and one is on the other breaker....5 neutral wires all spliced together.* Well, that's wrong, in spades. Neutrals for different circuits should not be joined.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Could you [edit] to post pictures of the switch wiring, please. Preferably the "before" picture we really hope you took? There are very rarely "extra" cables in a box - but there are very commonly cables that have functions you may not have considered, such as supplying power to the switches so they can supply it to their associated lights.

Comment: We seriously need a photo. It's very common for people to assume that all the neutral wires are "spares" and they should grab one and separate it from the others. Not at all; the neutrals being tied together are doing an important job and can't be separated without breaking stuff.  However your panel is an exception, since it has 2 circuits - neutrals from each circuit must be separated!  So you will end up with 2 groups.

Comment: So many? A light switch has no need to connect to neutral.

Comment: @Nelson well, technically it has to form part of a circuit that connects to neutral somewhere otherwise the light doesn't!

Comment: @Nelson smart switches generally _do_ need a neutral because there are electronics inside the switch itself that need to have power flowing in order for them to work. Old school dumb switches don't switch the neutral. (Actually, new smart switches don't switch it either, but they need to complete a circuit for their own function.)

Comment: Right, so the fact that the user busts open an existing light switch, complains about "all the neutrals", is extremely suspect. There's no good reason for the electrician to run a dedicated neutral to a dumb switch.

Comment: Since 2014 or 2017, @Nelson, NEC has required a neutral to every switch (effectively eliminating switch loops) because there are so many smart switches being installed. This means that every dumb switch in a spec home will have a neutral _in the box_ even though the switch doesn't need it. It's there for future use if/when needed.

Comment: Do your wires come into the box in cables? i.e. is there some white or yellow sheath grouping a batch of wires (black, white, bare, possibly a red) into a bundle before it leaves the box, or do all the wires just go out a hole? If you provide the pics others have asked for, we can help you determine this.